# Strong upper bound for consecutive p-smooth numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, asymptotics

Størmer's Theorem provides a method to find all consecutive p-smooth numbers. In Lehmer's paper [On a problem of Størmer](https://www.projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256067456), a very weak upper bound is given (Theorem 7). M. F. Hasler observes at [A002072](https://oeis.org/A002072) that, for $n$ primes, $10^n/n$ is an upper bound, except for $n=4$. This is in my view a very strong bound. Is there a proof of this result or a stronger bound than Lehmer's somewhere?

I made this graph to demonstrate how tight this bound is (extraordinarily close for a few small $n$):

[image]